# How can I get value by regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

This is sample code.

```
int myCodeVersion = 100;
```

My .py code as below.

```
fp = open(path, 'r').read()
myCodeVer = ''.join(map(str, re.findall('myCodeVersion'+ '\s=\s(.*?) ', fp))) 
print 'My Code version: ' + myCodeVer
```

This is result of my .py code

```
My Code version: 100;
```

I want to print only digit as below.

```
My Code version: 100
```

How can I fix the my regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myCodeVer = ''.join(map(str, re.findall('myCodeVersion'+ '\s=\s(\d*)', fp)))
```

Comment: Thx. But remove white space

Comment: `re.findall('myCodeVersion\s*=\s*(\d+)', fp)[0]` is enough. In fact, `\d*` is wrong, must be at least `\d+`.

Answer (score 2):

With that particular file you can do it like so:

```
import re

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    myCodeVer = re.findall('(?<=myCodeVersion)(?:\s*=\s*)(\d+)', f.read())
    print 'My Code version: ' + myCodeVer[0]
```

Output:

```
My Code version: 100
```

Regex:

`(?<=myCodeVersion)` - Positive look behind of `myCodeVersion`

`(?:\s*=\s*)` - Non capturing group, 0 or more spaces on either side of `=`

`(\d+)` - Capture 1 or more digits

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
.*\s*=\s*(.*?);
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more generic approach will be to to capture groups. For example, we can capture variable type, name and value as groups using the pattern-matcher as follows:

```
s = 'int myCodeVersion = 100;'
import re
# compile the regex pattern, if you need to use multiple times, it will be faster
pattern = re.compile(r"(int|float|double)\s+([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]+)\s*=\s*(\d+)\s*;") 
m = re.match(pattern, s)
print 'var type: ' + m.group(1)
print 'var name: ' + m.group(2)
print 'var value: ' + m.group(3)
#var type: int
#var name: myCodeVersion 
#var value: 100
```

For the  specific case you are interested in the code can be simplified to the following using the same approach:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"int\s+myCodeVersion\s*=\s*(\d+)\s*;")
print 'My Code version: ' + ''.join(map(str, re.match(pattern, s).group(1))) 
# My Code version: 100
```